# Indexes on small tables

Tags: sql-server, indexing

Is there any reason to put an index on a column, which is commonly used in a WHERE statement, or a JOIN, on a table that has less than 1000 rows? I am being asked, as a standard, for a project we're working on, to apply an index on all columns where a WHERE is being used.

I can understand the use of this on large tables, however, the overhead of the index on smaller tables seems - useless. Is there any benefit or detriment for adding indexes, willy-nilly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indices are there to avoid table scans - which lead to locks. Even a 1000 row table will get a lot less throughput without an index and given that no index is available in joins this will lead to certain constructs being favoured which you will not like in loops.

Answer (score 0):

Database index is only for large table that is correct. But when your small table is joining with other big table then without indexes it might be slow. At least one unique cluster index is 
Good practice to create in small table. 
This is also depends on what is your search, like text, search and join slow then numbers. 
my advice is to create one primary key cluster index on small table and other column index is not require if you are sure about less frequency of data.